# How to increase perfromance of SQL query for selecting from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Please help me, how to speed up this sql query?

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM ParametrickeVyhladavanie pa, 
     (SELECT p.*
     FROM produkty p
     WHERE p.KATEGORIA IN ('$categoryArray')) produkt
WHERE produkt.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', pa.code, '%')
AND produkt.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', pa.ValueCode, '%')
GROUP BY pa.code
```

Indexes:
pa.code, pa.ValueCode, p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE, p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE

> Showing rows 0 - 25 ( 26 total, Query took **20.4995 sec**)

**EDIT**
Actual code:

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM ParametrickeVyhladavanie pa
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM produkty p
   JOIN 
   PRODUCT_INFO AS pi
   ON p.ProId = pi.ProduktID
   AND p.KATEGORIA IN ('Mobily'))

AND pi.ATTRIBUTE_CODE = pa.AttributeCode
AND pi.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = pa.ValueCode
GROUP BY pa.code
```

This code says error `#1054 - Unknown column 'pi.ATTRIBUTE_CODE' in 'where clause'`
The `pi.` table working only between `(` and `)`

**EDIT - THIS IS ANSWER**

> I changed MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 5.5 and its faster!!!

Comment: This form of `like` does not allow for use of indexes. Perhaps you need to take step back and reevaluate the design.

Comment: Can I remove indexes?

Comment: You are using `Oracle`, `MySQL`, 'SQL Server'?

Comment: is there any common cloumn between ParametrickeVyhladavanie  and Producty ?

Comment: Don't remove indexes because they might still be useful elsewhere. But what I really ment was that database design brought you to this uneasy spot. Could you tell us what you want to do?

Comment: Do an 'explain' on the query, it shows what indexes are used and output the result here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: And by the way, try to avoid group by as much as possible unless you want to use an aggregate method like count, max etc.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović yes, here is screenshot http://i.imgur.com/3VSmhDj.jpg

Comment: This query shows all products in e-shop, and all possible parameters for parametric searching in actual category `$categoryArray`

Comment: If this is not set in stone you might move attribute_code and attribute_value from `Produkty` to new table, each pair in its own row accompanied by ProduktID (?). Create composite index on (attribute, value) pairs. Then you can join without `like` and use indexes. That is, if I'm correct about (attribute, value) being a pair - original query does not honor position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your database design is forcing a slow performance.

This will fix your performance problem:
You should create a new table(PRODUCT_INFO) and make foreign key pointing to the primary key of produkty.
Populate this table with the individual values from ATTRIBUTE_CODE and ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.

```
SELECT pa.code
FROM ParametrickeVyhladavanie pa
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM produkty p
JOIN 
PRODUCT_INFO AS pi
ON    p.ProId = pi.ProduktID
WHERE pi.ATTRIBUTE_CODE = pa.Code
AND pi.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = pa.ValueCode
AND p.KATEGORIA IN ('Mobily'))
GROUP BY pa.code
```

Comment: `#1317 - Query execution was interrupted`

Comment: Table like this? http://www.myscreen.cz/img/78940865200c7764a6948b9024c466685a69829f

Comment: What is pc? `**pc**.producty_ID`

Comment: @DavidLences leftover from when I changed the code from 2 tables to 1 table. Should have been *pi*

Comment: Thank you for help. One more error :( `#1054 - Unknown column 'pi.ATTRIBUTE_CODE' in 'where clause'` (line 10)

Comment: @DavidLences you didn't copy my code as it was. I took your code now with the correct columnnames. It should run exactly as written

Comment: I have the same column names, `ATTRIBUTE_CODE` and `ATTRIBUTE_VALUE`

Comment: error `#1054 - Unknown column 'pa.AttributeCode' in 'on clause'` I press ctrl+c and ctrl+v

Comment: Now again :'( `#1054 - Unknown column 'pa.code' in 'on clause'`

Comment: EXPLAIN without `AND pi.ATTRIBUTE_CODE = pa.Code
  AND pi.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = pa.ValueCode` screen: http://www.myscreen.cz/img/a613a4d33fbdd0ec32be04bb0aeaf39a41269916

Comment: @DavidLences I tried to move it to the where clause. I don't understand why it doesn't work. pa is refering to ParametrickeVyhladavanie and the column exists there

Answer (score 1):

You could try joining to `produkty` directly:

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM ParametrickeVyhladavanie pa
JOIN produkty p
  ON p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', pa.code, '%')
 AND p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', pa.ValueCode, '%')
 AND p.KATEGORIA IN ('$categoryArray')
GROUP BY pa.code
```

Comment: `Query took 22.7743 sec)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Code, ValueCode
    FROM ParametrickeVyhladavanie
) AS t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM produkty
    WHERE KATEGORIA IN ('$categoryArray')
        AND ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', t.code, '%')
        AND ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', t.ValueCode, '%')
)
```

Comment: aren't subqueries inside the where clause re-evaluated for each row?

Comment: @STT LCU for this need to see the query plan.

Comment: I am not sure, but i could imagine this performs better than my idea. +1 just in case

Comment: `#1317 - Query execution was interrupted` Too long loading maybe :-(

Answer (score 0):

how about this? use convert instead of concat

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM ParametrickeVyhladavanie pa
JOIN produkty p
ON p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'%')+ pa.code + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'%')
AND p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'%')+ pa.ValueCode+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'%')
AND p.KATEGORIA IN ('$categoryArray')
GROUP BY pa.code
```