# OleDB JOIN Syntax Not Correct

Tags: c#, select, oledb, where-clause

I recently asked a question on StackOverflow ([MySQL Returns All Rows When field = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802918/mysql-returns-all-rows-when-field-0/33803489?noredirect=1#comment55374618_33803489)) regarding a query statement not working in `MySQL`. I now have a very similar problem, this time using `OleDB` where I am trying to use a join to include fields that have `0` as an entry, but not select every field in the table as a result.

The new look `MySQL` query posted in the above question as the accepted answer works without a hitch. However the `OleDB` counterpart I have written to do almost the same does not. It's a bit messy as the tables are not named very well (I didn't create this database) and I'm getting a simple syntax error;

```
myQuery.CommandText = "SELECT s.scm_num, s.scm_name, c.cr3_text, q.qsp_value, s.scm_bprefix, s.scm_nxbnum FROM qspreset q INNER JOIN sdccomp s LEFT OUTER JOIN cntref3 c ON s.scm_cntref3=c.cr3_id AND q.qsp_relat=s.scm_invtype AND q.qsp_what=13";
```

I'm querying another table here as well as the two involved in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and I believe that is where I am making the mistake.

Comment: `INNER JOIN sdccomp s` on what?  You have to specify which columns are linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join conditions need to be with the join

```
myQuery.CommandText = 
"SELECT s.scm_num, s.scm_name, c.cr3_text, q.qsp_value, s.scm_bprefix, s.scm_nxbnum    
FROM qspreset q   
INNER JOIN sdccomp s 
      on q.qsp_relat = s.scm_invtype AND q.qsp_what = 13  
LEFT OUTER JOIN cntref3 c 
      ON s.scm_cntref3 = c.cr3_id";
```

q.qsp_what = 13 can be moved to a where

I happen to like this style
In the case of MSSQL T-SQL and some queries with a lot of joins I have gotten more efficient query plan by moving a where condition up into a join.  The filter happened early rather that last.

If you don't believe you can put a hard value in a join see [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9cf54/2)

Comment: And the `q.qsp_what` should simply be in a where. Good catch.

Comment: @Luaan Are you sure it will not work in the join also.  I do it like that with TSQL.

Comment: It will work in T-SQL, but it definitely *belongs* in a where - it's not a join condition, it's a simple filter. T-SQL is rather forgiving - other languages might not be so happy with something like that.

Comment: Conditions on tables that you're joining *to* belong in the `on` clause for that join - `qspreset` is the table you're joining *from*, so conditions on that table only belong in the `where` clause.

Comment: @MarkBannister Only?   I added a SQLfiddle MySQL 5.6 that indicates you can put a hard value in a join.

Comment: @Frisbee: *belong* is not the same as *can get away with* - you *can get away with* stealing your grandmother's false teeth, but this does not mean they *belong* to you.

Comment: Then you need to stop stealing grandma's teeth  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011883/how-to-increase-perfromance-of-sql-query-for-selecting-from-2-tables/18012170#18012170

Comment: @Frisbee: The first two `on` conditions in the linked answer are comparing values between the two tables, while the third condition is on a value from the table that is being linked *to* - as I said in my previous comment, **"Conditions on tables that you're joining to belong in the on clause for that join"**. Grandma's teeth remain in her possession.

Comment: @MarkBannister Linked to?  A join symmetric.   Switch the from and join tables is the same join.   So if I switched q and s that would make a difference to you?  Again do you any evidence that in the join will produce incorrect results?

Comment: "You can lead a man to knowledge, but you cannot make him think." Try rephrasing your last sentence in English.

Comment: Oh so now it is English.  Really you don't know what that sentence  means?   What about that switch q and s that you conveniently did not address?